# How to delete query param when routed to specific route in angular?

Tags: angular, angular-router

AFAIK, to remove query param in angular, we need to do the following:

```
this.router.navigate([], {
  queryParams: {
    sample_param: null,
  },
  queryParamsHandling: 'merge'
})
```

However, this doesn't work when trying to add on the route guard, resolver, or anything that is being added to routing module, since this routes to the current route before routing to the target.

The reason why I'm not trying to add this logic to either by subscribing to router.events or do it on ngOnInit of the routed component is because first, by doing on router.events will subscribe to all route changes and this makes it difficult to just remove query param "only" when the target component is initiated, and second, applying the logic on ngOnInit will work fine but the issue here is that it's hard to reuse the code, where it only removes specific query param/s.

That's why I'm trying to create a guard/resolver, that can be reused on several routes and only done before/on component is initiated.

Thanks in advance!